# no data is getting retrieved when try to run query, select [column_name] from [table_name] in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

In Redshift when I run the query:

```
select * 
from [table_name]
```

I am getting the output, but when I run:

```
select [column_name] 
from [table_name]
```

I'll get the column name but no other data.

Only the `select *` query is working, if I put any condition then it doesn't give me any output. I'm running the query with the account I created the table. Why is this happening?